# Работа с массивом очередей

Tags: c#, winforms

Здравствуйте,приложение на winforms, в котором будет "моделироваться" банковская очередь.
Создан массив очередей `Queue<int>[] QArray`, количество очередей подается с текстбокса,затем в каждую из очередей массив записываются номера,количество клиентов в очереди выводится на лейблы.

```
M = int.Parse(textBox1.Text); //Количество очередей 
        QArray = new Queue<int>[M];
        int element = 0;
                 for(int i=0;i< M; i++)
        {

            Random rnd = new Random();
            int m = rnd.Next(1, 8);//Количество элементов в очереди
            for (int j = 0; j <m; j++)
            {
                element = rnd.Next(3, 30);
               QArray[i].Enqueue(element); // ОШИБКА
            }
        }
        for (int i=0;i< M; i++)
        {
            var labelnumber = i;
            var label = new Label();
            {
                Location = new Point(46, 132 + i * 15);
                Text = QArray[M].Count.ToString() ;
            }
            this.Controls.Add(label);
        }
```

После ввода значения в текстбокс появляется исключение "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.".Подскажите в чем проблема,пожалуйста.

Comment: Когда Вы исправите ошибку, которую Вам объяснил andreycha, Вас ждут другие. `var label = new Label();` - перенесите ";" в после "}". `QArray[M]` - index out of bounds.

Comment: И пожалуйста, не используйте однобуквенные имена переменных, отличающиеся только регистром.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы инициализировали *массив* очередей:

```
QArray = new Queue<int>[M];
```

Но не создали *сами очереди*. Делайте так:

```
QArray = new Queue<int>[M];
int element = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
{
    QArray[i] = new Queue<int>();

    // остальной код
}
```